# Making my code shorter in C

Tags: c, if-statement

```
for (c = 0; c < SIZE-4; ++c)
    for (r = 0; r < SIZE; ++r)
        if (board[r][c] == cross && board[r][c+1] == cross && board[r][c+2] == cross && board[r][c+3] == cross && board[r][c+4] == cross)
            return true;
```

I am working on my Tic-Tac-Toe in C (with custom size board, 5 needed in a row to win). I have this really-really long 'if', which I want to make shorter. I also have this code 4 times becuase of the row, column, diag, antidiag, so it needs some fix.

Comment: This is better suited on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Downvoter no it's not, this isn't really a complete example at all.

Comment: Recurrent task like complex check are usually better done with a dedicated function ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving some of the code into a function might be helpful, something like this:

```
bool rowHasNCrosses(int board[][SIZE], int r, int c, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (((c + i) >= SIZE) || (board[r][c+i] != cross)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

for (int c = 0; c < SIZE - 4; ++c) {
  for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; ++r) {
    if (rowHasNCrosses(board, r, c, 5)) return true;
  }
}
```

You could then do similar things for column and diagonal test. However, I suspect there is a more efficient algorithm than this to determine if the game has been won.

Comment: I tried to think of a better algorithm, but without any success.
Thanks for the answer this solves the problem but it's not shorter that much, because every for loop has different limits, so I can't use just one and put all my functions there.

Comment: That's fine, and it's probably ok to start with a brute force solution that checks the entire board, given that it's a small board. One obvious optimization that springs to mind is that you only have to test for game won after a player makes a move and then you only have to test for spaces adjacent to that position (up, down, diag) so you don't have to test the entire board.

Comment: And what happends when the player puts in a corner for example. How can I prevent over-indexing?

Comment: As in any situation with boundaries, either the test function itself does the bounds checking (e.g. testing that c+i < SIZE) or the caller of the test function is responsible for doing this. Have edited example code to show the former.

Comment: And what if I want to make a computer AI? (because I need to make a player vs computer game). I have sooo many for and if statements, it just looks gross. Basically what I did so far: used this method to find out whether they are next to each other or not. I covered up most of the cases and the computer can play kinda good but I have hundreds of lines just for this function and it is not right. Do you have an idea how to make it shorter/more efficient?

Comment: I think you're basically asking how to become a better programmer. Lots of options: web searches, programming classes, help from friends/colleagues who are themselves good programmers, read code in open source projects to see how they are written, and just do lots of hands-on programming.